# How can I receive payment in multiple currency in wordpress Woocommerce?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, currency

I just installed wordpress and woocommerce, my default currency is USD.

Now when I convert the currency on store it is working smooth. I mean it is changing from USD to INR.

Now say I want to make payment in INR and product cost is USD100 and after converting currency it display INR6500 but when I checkout it pass INR100 to payment gateways.

Kindly suggest.

Answer (score 0):

I was using a plugin long back, [currency swicher](https://wordpress.org/plugins/woocommerce-currency-switcher/). This plugin will change your plugin will convert your customer's currency automatically based on their addresses. But you have to enter the conversion rates for currency in admin panel and have to keep updated.

If you can code something like getting conversation rates from a live api and update that list then it will be superb. But still if you can manage updating rates manually , it can work like charm.